# Word Mac 16.13 BUG: curly quotes and em dashes replaced with random text

Tags: microsoft-word, file-corruption

I have been experiencing an issue in Word 16.13 on a Mac. It would be good if anyone knew about what causes this and how to avoid it.

**Summary**

A document I was working on recently started showing corruption.  Example:

Original:

> In “Fragile Storage, Digital Futures” (2015) Bollmer considers the
>   paradoxes around “the specific material conditions required to
>   preserve and maintain digital storage, which is too often imagined as
>   both ephemeral and everlasting”.

Corruption:

> In ss, new types of genres such as s, and ediBollmer considers the
>   paradoxes around athe specific material conditions required to
>   preserve and maintain digital storage, which is too often imagined as
>   both ephemeral and everlasting”.

So, in the above fragment you can see that

> “Fragile Storage, Digital Futures” (2015)

Was replaced with:

> ss, new types of genres such as s, and edi

The issue seems to be related to curly quotes and em-dashes: wherever there is a curly quote (single or double) or an em dash in the original, the corruption occurs - you can see this in the above snippet.

The changes between the original and the corrupted versions were:

- applying a new template to the document
- applying styles consistently throughout the document (the original had a mix of
  different paragraph styles)
- a global search and replace to change -ise and -isation to -ize and -ization

If anyone else has come across this problem before and can give me more information I'd appreciate it.  I can't seem to find anything online, and I don't believe I'm the only one to ever experience this!

Answer (score 0):

You list four issues, although you list just one example problem, so I’ll take the best stab at what could be happening There are several options:

Regarding the curly quotes replacing text. You don’t mention when it happens. I’m assuming the moment you type the final quote. If it happens at Open, the below is less relevant.

- Check in Preferences → Autocorrect → Autocorrect tab. It is possible your template has predefined autocorrects that does the replace. I just tested with adding “DVD” (with quotes) to be replaced with “Digital Versatile Disk” (no quotes). The moment I typed the final quotation mark, the word was replaced in-situ with the phrase. Note that it is possible to also replace a placeholder text with formatted text (although I have no experience with that).
- You can also check the System Preferences → Keyboard → Text options for a similar (if profile-wide) instant replace feature.
- Another possibility is that you might have TextExpander or something like this set up, with a badly defined snippet. They are inordinately powerful, and could easily do what you expect.

As for your other three issues:

**Applying a New Template to the Document**
My assumption is that this is on open. This is likely due to you having a different default dotm template (see below) or that the document has additional templates attached (Tools → Templates and Add-ins..), although this is less likely.

**Applying styles consistently throughout to a document** and **Global changes from —ize to -ise**
Is this a document from another OS/version of Word that you’re opening for editing? 
These point very clearly to different machines set up for different locales. At the bottom of the Word window, it should show you “English (), and the differences appear to be that the document was written using US spelling and is being autocorrected to US British (or one of the other variants that use British English spelling as their base. This type of autocorrect typically only happens when a Spell Check is run, or as-you-type, however.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds to me like an issue with your character encoding. It could be that whatever character encoding you are using on your Mac is unable to process curly quotes. I had a similar issue on a Windows PC, except that the curly quotes were actually changing into ?s instead of text strings. Try seeing if you can change the character encoding on Word. I am not a Mac user though, so I cannot help you in that area.